# Generate random number and place it inside image URL

Tags: javascript, random

I want to generate a random number and place it inside an image URL. I found this JS code on the web but it doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
number=Math.random()*10000000000000000;
</script>

<img src="https://link.com/number="/>
```

Can someone see whats wrong with the code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: On the pool, I have this as getting downvoted 8 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm curious as to where you received your example from, since that's really not doing anything.

The example is creating a random number and doing **nothing** with it.

You'll first need to add a class or ID to your image and then query the dom for it.

```
<img id="the-image" src="https://link.com/number="/>
```

Once you do so, you'll have to append the generated number to the image's `src`

```
var image = document.querySelector('#the-image');

var number = Math.random() * 10000000000000000;

image.src += number;
```

Here's a working [example](https://jsbin.com/puroyavezu/1/edit?html,js,output). Since the image URL is invalid, I've `alert`ed the value for proof.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
<img id="image" src="https://link.com/number="/>

<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
number = Math.random() * 10000000000000000;
document.getElementById('image').src += number;
</script>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('image')` doesn't exist yet. OP won't realize this

Answer (score 1):

The pathname on that img will be read literally as 'number='. If you want to use the number you generated, you're going to have to use javascript to alter the url using string concatenation.

Also, use `var` when declaring a variable.

This should do it:

```
var number = Math.random() * 10000000000000000;

var img = document.querySelector('img');

img.src = 'https://link.com/number=' + number;
```